# Creating Customized TitleBar and Tabbed Panes in Java Application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I am working on the UI for a particular java application. I need to create a UI like this, can someone direct me as to what all to use to create this:

[image: Required GUI]

I am Sorry for the Paint Image. Hope it does the Purpose:-|.  What I specifically need is -

1. The Pink Tab containing the Application Title is always constant whereas the text in nearby label (written as "Changing title will vary).
2. Also,the tabs - tab 1,2 and 3 need to be in the shape of a rectangle with circular ends.And these tabs should function as the tabs in a `JTabbedPane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) only the way would be use [Custom Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968), part of them override `BasicTabbedPaneUI` and correctly

2) you can use [customized and colorized BasicTabbedPaneUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7056093/714968), there are only about `Colors`, I leaving to override 4 navigations buttons and `AbstractIcons` inside those `AbstractButtons`

3) use most complex [BasicTabbedPaneUI by aephyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734016/714968),

4) for Customized `TittleBar` to create the `JPanel` with `GradientPaint`

Comment: Could You be elaborate the answer, Please?

Comment: See also [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg).