# Force JOptionPane to Stay Open

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drop-down-menu, joptionpane

My application is constructed as follows:

- Main window allows user to select CSV file to be parsed
- JOptionPane appears after a CSV file is selected and the JOptionPane contains a drop-down menu with various choices; each of which generates a separate window
- Currently, the JOptionPane closes after a selection is made from the menu and the "OK" button is clicked

I am looking for a way to force the JOptionPane to remain open so that the user can select something different if they want. I would like the JOptionPane to be closed only by clicking the "X" in the upper right corner. I am also open to other possibilities to achieve a similar result if using a JOptionPane isn't the best way to go on this.

Here is the relevant block of code I'm working on:

```
try 
{
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath), ',');

    // Reads the complete file into list of tokens.
    List<String[]> rowsAsTokens = null;

    try 
    {
        rowsAsTokens = reader.readAll();
    } 

    catch (IOException e1) 
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] menuChoices = { "option 1", "option 2", "option 3" };

    String graphSelection = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "Choose from the following options...", "Choose From DropDown", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
            menuChoices, // Array of menuChoices
            menuChoices[0]); // Initial choice

    String menuSelection = graphSelection;

    // Condition if first item in drop-down is selected
    if (menuSelection == menuChoices[0] && graphSelection != null)
    {
        log.append("Generating graph: " + graphSelection + newline);

        option1();          
    }

    if (menuSelection == menuChoices[1] && graphSelection != null)
    {

        log.append("Generating graph: " + graphSelection + newline);

        option2();      
    }

    if (menuSelection == menuChoices[2] && graphSelection != null)
    {
        log.append("Generating graph: " + graphSelection + newline);

        option3();
    }

    else if (graphSelection == null)
    {   
        log.append("Cancelled." + newline);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: might be better to put your drop down in a different jframeinstead of an option pane, that will give you more behavior options

Comment: I've also noticed that you are comparing `String`s using `==`. This is not the way to do it in `Java`. You should use `equals()` method instead: `menuSelection.equals(menuChoice[0])`

Comment: @Michael - why is the equals() method preferrable?

Comment: @THEDOCTOR In `Java` the `==` notation is used to compare primitives e.g. `int a = 4; int b = 4; return a == b;` will result in `TRUE`. If you will try to compare two `Objects` like `String`s using `==` it will test if the `Object`s are the same (or, to be precise, it will test if the `reference` is the same). e.g. `String c = "Test"; String d = "Test"; return c == d;` will result in `False`. But `return c.equals(d);` will result in `True`.

Comment: @THEDOCTOR You are more than welcome. Just out of curiosity, have you solved your original issue?

Comment: Not yet. I have been looking through everyone's answers and I am still trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like for the window with the choices to remain open even after
>   the user has selected an option so that they can select another option
>   if they wish. How do I get the JOptionPane to remain open instead of
>   its default behavior where it closes once a drop-down value is
>   selected?

- this is basic property, by default `JOptionPane` is disposed, this isn't possible without dirty hacks, don't do that
- use `JDialog` (could, may be undecorated) with proper value for [ModalityType](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/dialog-modality.html)
- you can to use some of variations for `Java & Ribbon`
- you can to put desired choices to the [JComboBox or JMenu with JMenuItems (very nice of ways) to the JLayer or GlassPane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734016/714968)
- I think that this is standard job for `JMenu` or [JToolBar](https://java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0980__JToolBar.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In either of these option panes, I can change my choice as many times as I like before closing it.  The 3rd option pane will show (default to) the value selected earlier in the 1st - the current value.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Options {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Object[] options = {
                    "Option 1",
                    "Option 2",
                    "Option 3",
                    "None of the above"
                };
                JComboBox optionControl = new JComboBox(options);
                optionControl.setSelectedIndex(3);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, optionControl, "Option",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                System.out.println(optionControl.getSelectedItem());

                String graphSelection = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null,
                        "Choose from the following options...", 
                        "Choose From DropDown",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                        options, // Array of menuChoices
                        options[3]); // Initial choice
                System.out.println(graphSelection);

                // show the combo with current value!
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, optionControl, "Option",
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

I think Michael guessed right with a `JList`.  Here is a comparison between [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364787/how-do-you-import-a-font/8365030#8365030) & [combo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965038/getting-fonts-sizes-bold-etc/6965149#6965149).

[image] [image]

Note that both `JList` & `JComboBox` can use a renderer as seen in the combo.  The important difference is that a list is an embedded component that supports multiple selection.

Comment: *"I would like for the window with the choices to remain open"*  If by 'window' you mean the option pane - it does stay open.  If you mean the combo drop-down, it is a drop-down, **not a window!**

Answer (score 1):

The following solution won't give you a drop-down menu but it will allow you to select multiple values.

You can use a `JList` to store your choices and to use `JOptionPane.showInputMessage` like this:

```
JList listOfChoices = new JList(new String[] {"First", "Second", "Third"});
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, listOfChoices, "Select Multiple Values...", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

Using the method `getSelectedIndices()` on `listOfChoices` after the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` will return an array of integers that contains the indexes that were selected from the `JList` and you can use a `ListModel` to get their values:

```
int[] ans = listOfChoices.getSelectedIndices();
ListModel listOfChoicesModel = listOfChoices.getModel();
for (int i : ans) {
    System.out.println(listOfChoicesModel.getElementAt(i));
}
```

Comment: As soon as I saw your answer, I heard a penny drop.  I think you have got it right for what the OP actually needs.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks :) He wanted a drop down list... It's not the same, but if he doesn't have a lot of values this can do the trick.

Comment: While this allows the user to select multiple values, the JOptionPane still closes once the "OK" button is clicked. I want the user to continue to have the ability to select items even after the initial selection.

Comment: @THEDOCTOR Yes, the user can select multiple values using the `ctrl` button plus the `left mouse button`.

Comment: I saw that, but my point it closes after you click OK and I don't want it to close.

Comment: @THEDOCTOR You want your `OK` button to act like an `Apply` button? You can create a custom dialog to achieve this. But the question that arises is: Why do you want this behavior?

Comment: Currently, the user has to select the CSV file to parse and then the JOptionPane appears. If they want to select a different option, they have to browse for the CSV file all over again and then the JOptionPane will appear again. Each selection launches a statistics graph and they might want to see more than one. I want to allow the user to keep choosing from the available options without having to start over again with browsing for and opening the CSV file. As mentioned, I am open to possibilities other than the JOptionPane if something different would be more suitable.

Comment: @THEDOCTOR Hi, I'm sorry that I didn't reply for your last post. Did you manage to solve it?