# Draw something on JButton's right and top corner

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I am trying to create JButton such as there must be a number painted on the top and right corner of JButton.

For example, in case of notification buttons there is a message in the button, how is that possible? Can the help be taken of paint method to draw the label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are three ways, by using

1. [GlassPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729692/can-i-have-a-jtabbedpane-with-a-jmenubar/9734016#9734016)
2. [JLayer (Java7) based on JXLayer(Java6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)
3. [JButtton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) (all JComponents) is container too, there is easy and possible use [standard LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) (only `JFrame == BorderLayout` and `JPanel == FlowLayout` have got implemented `LayoutManager in API` directly), [then basically everything is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575641/how-returns-xxxsize-from-jcomponents-added-to-the-jlabel)

Answer (score 2):

`JButton` and any `JComponent` extend `Container` class, so you should be able to add elements into `JButton` as if it were a simple panel. So in your case you can add a JLabel with your text into a button.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider implementing `Icon` to decorate the button; [`ColorIcon`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) is a simple example. You can use the color to signify buttons that are likely to need attention, and you can use `drawString()` specify a number.