# Tabed pane with a label on top

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, overlay, jtabbedpane

I need to add a JLabel/JPanel as shown in the image. When resizing the frame both the tabbed pane and the Label/panel should be resided. The label and the panel inside the Tabbed Pane are independent. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example to use JLayer(as suggested by mKorbel):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class TopRightCornerLabelLayerUITest {
  public static JComponent makeUI() {
    JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
    tab.addTab("New tab1", new JLabel("1"));
    tab.addTab("New Tab2", new JLabel("2"));
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JLayer<JComponent>(tab, new TopRightCornerLabelLayerUI()));
    return p;
  }
  private static void createAndShowUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
class TopRightCornerLabelLayerUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> {
  private JLabel l = new JLabel("A Label at right corner");
  private JPanel rubberStamp = new JPanel();
  @Override public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    super.paint(g, c);
    Dimension d = l.getPreferredSize();
    int x = c.getWidth() - d.width - 5;
    SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, l, rubberStamp, x, 2, d.width, d.height);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great !!  Working...Thanks a lot

Comment: Can u please tell me how to add a JPopupMenu to this label ("A Label at right corner") to add some menu items on this label. pleaseee

Comment: I guess you might want to override `LayerUI#processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l)` and do it like this: `if(labelRect.contains(pt) && e.isPopupTrigger()) popup.show(tabbedPane, pt.x, pt.y);`

Answer (score 2):

> I need to add a JLabel/JPanel as shown in the image. When resizing the
>   frame both the tabbed pane and the Label/panel should be resided. The
>   label and the panel inside the Tabbed Pane are independent.. If any
>   one have the solution, please help me.

You can use:

1. [JLayer (Java7) based on JXLayer(Java6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)
2. GlassPane, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9734016/714968)

---

I'd use JLayer if is possible (requires Java7).