# Floating JPanel above a JPanel with BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a `JPanel` called `pnlMain` with a layout set to `BorderLayout`. Inside the panel are three `JPanel` added to `PAGE_START`, `CENTER`, and `PAGE_END`. Now, my requirement is if the Settings button is clicked, it will display a transparent `JPanel` above `pnlMain`. This transparent panel will then contain an opaque, smaller, centered panel, that will contain the settings stuff.

I know I can do this using `JLayeredPane`, but looking at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html#layout) it says that you can only put components of different depth using absolute positioning which I'm aware is highly discouraged.

Is there some other way to do this without using absolute positioning?

Comment: FYI- You can use a layout manager with `JLayeredPane`, but you'd need a layout manager that will allow you to place components ontop of each other, like `GridBagLayout`, but there are probably easier solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the glass pane of the parent frame, which will allow you to add components to it that will appear to overlaid over the main content.

Basically, I would, create a `JPanel` and set it to be transparent (`setOpaque(false)`).  I would set it's layout manager to something like `GridBagLayout` (as it will use the preferred size of the child component and center it automatically within it's parent container).

Onto this panel I would then add the `Settings` panel.

Finally, I would set the parent frame's glass pane to the first (backing) pane and make it visible.

```
frame.getRootPane().setGlassPane(backingPane); // Or similar
```

Take a look at [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

**Updated**

If you can't use the glass pane of the top level frame yourself, then you need to fake it.

This example basically uses a `JLayeredPane` backed by a `GridBagLayout`

[image]

If you add a `MouseListener` and `KeyListener` to the background pane you can consume events going to the child components.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FloatingPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FloatingPane();
    }

    public FloatingPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final WorkPane workPane = new WorkPane();
                JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
                settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        workPane.toggleSettings();
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(workPane);
                frame.add(settings, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class WorkPane extends JLayeredPane {
        private final BackingPane backingPane;

        public WorkPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(createLabel("Center", Color.BLUE), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            add(createLabel("Left", Color.RED), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(createLabel("Right", Color.GREEN), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            backingPane = new BackingPane();
            backingPane.add(new SettingsPane());
            backingPane.setVisible(false);
            add(backingPane, gbc);

            setLayer(backingPane, DEFAULT_LAYER + 1);

        }

        public void toggleSettings() {

            backingPane.setVisible(!backingPane.isVisible());

        }

        protected JLabel createLabel(String text, Color bg) {

            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(bg);

            return label;

        }
    }

    public class BackingPane extends JPanel {

        public BackingPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(new Color(128, 128, 128, 192));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

    }

    public class SettingsPane extends JPanel {

        public SettingsPane() {

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            add(new JLabel("Settings"));

        }
    }
}
```

Another solution might be to fake the entire glass pane by taking a snap shot of the current panel and using a `CardLayout`, flip to the settings pane, using the snap shot as the backgound image for the settings pane (which can could then apply effects to like gray scaling and bluring)

Comment: :D At least I helped some one today

Comment: Mr. @MadProgrammer is there a way to do this in `JPanel` layer because my `JPanel` might be embedded in a bigger frame, that means if I call on the `getRootPane()` it will return the bigger frame then the glasspane will be applied to the bigger frame. Is it not?

Comment: @onepotato [agree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9734016/714968), but for Java7 to use [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

Comment: @mKorbel As I understand it, `JLayer` is a decorator, which doesn't allow for real time interaction with components (stuff is just painted) - could be wrong as I've only used `JXLayer`

Comment: @MadProgrammer 1. agree, yes from this point of view, this is true, is about illusion done by paint/paintComponent/paintIcon/paintChildren, there aren't accesible Key/MouseEvents directly in compare with GLassPane, 2. back to the end still no idea where going OPS sentence == `that will the settings stuff.`, then reason for my comment here

Comment: @mKorbel Cool, just want to make sure :P

Comment: @onepotato I've added an additional example based on my comment to the main question

Comment: more than basic stuff about JLayer is [l(as always) in post by @aterai](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A177145+jlayer)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for the additional example. I will use that instead.

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 thanks, I found it interesting and trying to learn from it.  Could you explain the benefit of overriding  paintComponent(Graphics g) in BackingPane, over simply setting setBackground(new Color(128, 128, 128, 192)); ?

Comment: @OferYuval Swing can't handle alpha based colors when applied to the background color of a component, Swing components are either opaque or they're not.  This is track, making the component transparent, we then use `paintComponent` to paint the translucent color ourselves, thus preserving the way painting works and getting the desired effect

Comment: @MadProgrammer  thanks for the quick response. When I omit  setOpaque(false); and add setBackground(new Color(128, 128, 128, 192));  in the constructor, and also omit  paintComponent(Graphics g) , I get the same visual result. What do I miss ?

Comment: @OferYuval Try adding other components to the UI and trigger some repaints, especially those which are supposed to occur underneath the component. You may not always get a glitch, but when you do, it will be tremendously awesome and the which is source  of more than a few questions on SO